# Portability of sqlite database using custom tokenizer

Tags: sqlite, fts3

I have a sqlite database, which uses custom tokenizers:

Do all clients, which want to read from this database, require the same tokenizer in their sqlite-driver? Or are the internal tokenizer data structures ready to use without implementation of custom tokenizers?

Comment: What do you mean with "custom tokenizer"? Data is stored within tokens in database? Or do you mean custom collation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tokenizer is applied to both the inserted data and the search string, so every application that accesses a database must have installed any custom tokenizers used in that database.

Comment: What is your advice, if an iphone app needs to use german locale in order to do full text search including stemming?

Comment: If you are using a custom German tokenizer, you have to install it if you want to use it.